# Text in new Div under background video

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Im struggling to find a solution to putting a new div with text under the back ground video.

Here's what I have:

https://jsfiddle.net/9me45b63/

```
<header>
  <div>
    <div class="video-container">
      <video autoplay muted id="Mattvideo">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Text centred and justified between bottom of NavBar and bottom of video</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<p>Text Under Video</p>
```

And also justifying the H1 text to be in the centre middle of the video. My video is much larger and covers 70% height of the page.

Many thanks.
Kyle

Comment: Is it important that your video be in the header and your text outside it?

Comment: If so, you may want to implement Bootstrap's grid in both cases so things align. I'd try to update your Bootstrap library, too. Many fixes since 4.0.0.